# easiest way to watch mkv movies on lumia 530

Tags: lumia, video

What is the easiest way to watch mkv movies on my lumia 530?
Unfortunately my phone does not read natively this video format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Moliplayer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/moliplayer-pro/9wzdncrfhwbv) or [VLC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/vlc-for-windows-phone/9wzdncrcv5tl), both support MKV file and most of the formats.

Answer (score 0):

Try VLC for Windows Phone: https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/store/p/vlc-for-windows-phone/9wzdncrcv5tl (but I don't know, if it really works, couldn't test it).